# Finding probability with replacement

Tags: probability

Three light bulbs are picked with replacement from a bucket with 15 bulbs of which 5 are broken.

What is the probability that...

1.) None of the bulbs picked are broken.

2.) Exactly one of the bulbs picked is broken.

3.) At least one of the bulbs picked is broken.

With number 1, I did 10^3 / 15^3 which is 8/27. Is this correct?

I have no idea how to do 2 and 3. Please help, I'm really bad with probability. :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If exactly 1 bulb is picked, it could be picked wither the first time, second time, or third time.  So
$$P(X=1)=3\cdot\frac{5}{15}\cdot\frac{10^2}{15^2}$$
This is the case since we have
$$\text{ broken  normal  normal }$$
$$\text{ normal  broken  normal }$$
$$\text{ normal  normal  broken }$$
Each of these will have the same probablility so we multiply by 3.

FOr the third example, what is the complement of your problem?  If you have at least one, then $P(X\ge 1)=1-P(X<0)$ which you alread found...

Now more formally, your random variable $X$ is the number of defective bulbs you select from a pile after three trials with replacement.  We can call success selecting a non broken bulb.  Your random variable $X\sim binom(3,2/3)$.  Thus
$$P(X=x)=\binom{3}{x}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^x\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{3-x}$$
and
$$P(X\le x)=\sum_{k=0}^3\binom{3}{x}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^x\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{3-x}$$

Comment: For the second one. We multiply by 3 because we choose 3 times. We multiply that by 5/15 because that's the probability of choosing a broken light bulb in one pick. But why do we multiply by 10^2 / 15^2?

Comment: You have two more picks; each pick results in a nonbroken bulb since you've chosen exactly one broken one.  THus the remaining two are nonbroken.  The probability of selecting a nonbroken bulb is $10/15$, so the probability of selecting two nonbroken bulbs is $10^2/15^2$.

Comment: Ok, so the probability for the third one is 1 - 8/27 = 19/27.

Comment: yes.  The complement of "at least one" is ... none!  You already calculated the probability of no broken bulbs, so now take it's complement for problem 3.